# Excel - I want to get all the cells adjacent to a keyword on a page onto another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, search, spreadsheet, productivity

I'm using Excel to track what I do every day, which includes a lot of qualitative data, and at the end of every day I write down how many hours are spent in each of several categories. I definitely made this from a beginner level of Excel experience to make sense for aesthetics, not utility. So there's a 2x6 section every day that's boxed that says the categories in the first column and the number of hours in the cells directly to the right of the category name. Lots of other things occur in these rows and columns in the wider sheet, but like every 24-29th entry in columns C or I is the same six activity categories, and the hours spent are the 24-29th entries in D or J.

Basically, I want to write a formula in a 2nd sheet that looks through the whole first sheet for a word and grabs all the cells adjacent to its occurrences (like, "sleep" or "social"). Really I want to add up all the times next to each occurrence for a given word, but it would be fine to just transport them over and do the adding on the 2nd sheet. Does anyone have any idea how this can be accomplished, if it's even possible, or if I should reorganize everything (if so, advice welcome on that too)?

Comment: [Filter with partial text](https://superuser.com/questions/1683776/excel-i-want-to-get-all-the-cells-adjacent-to-a-keyword-on-a-page-onto-another) try this maybe you can find the answer

Answer (score 0):

[image: Filter_partial text]

try as will something like this to give you a hint to come up with your result